# Using the Coverage Python API to get coverage results after a run

Tags: python, markdown, coverage.py

I want to generate a Markdown report after a coverage run, so I tried to use the [Python API](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4.2/api.html), particularly the `CoverageData` class.  I can get the lines covered with `CoverageData.lines(<file>)`, however I don't see how to get the percentage.  Any pointers?

Comment: Percentages are calculated by the [`coverage.results.Numbers`](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/8ab9ff17409e3f6f3f5f2c0076d8b3250e8da4a0/coverage/results.py#L171) class. It is called by each of the "report" builders (html, json, xml, etc.) to do those calculations. See the [jsonreport](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/8ab9ff17409e3f6f3f5f2c0076d8b3250e8da4a0/coverage/jsonreport.py) as an example.

Comment: @Waylan thanks for the hint!  I'll look, however for my current need I worked up a solution by working with the json output from `coverage json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `coverage json` command to get a JSON data file, then process it however you like.  It will be easier than using the API.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing in the end :-p